# Link domain nameservers with VPS

Tags: domains, dns, vps, nameserver

I have bought a domain with online.az and I want to link it with my VPS from GoDaddy, The domain provider only allows you to add nameservers and does not allow you to add your server IP address.

I have tried to add `ns1.secureserver.net` and `ns2.secureserver.net` as name servers in online.az which are default nameserver in my VPS but that didn't work.

I have contacted online.az and asked them how to add A records but they said they only offer nameservers to connect to hosting.

**How to connect my .az domain to my VPS in this case?**

Comment: This might help. Try finding the nameservers for your domain in your GoDaddy hosting, then set your nameservers at online.az to those nameservers. https://www.godaddy.com/help/find-my-godaddy-nameservers-12318

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by Add DNS hosting of .az domain to Godaddy and that gave me 2 nameservers form domaincontrol.com that I pointed my domain to.

Then from Godaddy again I pointed to my server.

Answer (score 1):

At your domain registrar, your `NS` records point to your DNS host.  At your DNS host, your `A` and `CNAME` records point to your web host.

It sounds like you want to use online.az as your domain registrar and GoDaddy as both your DNS host and your web host. To make that happen you should:

1. Set up hosting at GoDaddy: https://www.godaddy.com/hosting/web-hosting  I believe that GoDaddy provides DNS hosting included with web hosting. So you shouldn't have to [add DNS hosting](https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-dns-hosting-20165) as a separate GoDaddy Product.
2. If you didn't specify your domain as the "primary domain" when you set up your GoDaddy hosting account, add the domain to your account: https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-domains-8342
3. Follow GoDaddy's instructions for figuring out which nameservers are assigned to your domain: https://www.godaddy.com/help/find-my-godaddy-nameservers-12318 (Maybe you already did this and that is where you got the `secureserver.net` information.)
4. Update the `NS` records at your domain registrar (online.az) to match the NS records that GoDaddy provides.
5. I believe that when GoDaddy hosts your site and your DNS it will automatically create the proper `A` records for your site.  You can verify them.  Get the IP address that GoDaddy has assigned by starting to follow the instructions for adding `A` records: https://www.godaddy.com/help/change-an-a-record-19239 (Just don't change anything.)
6. Wait two days because it could take a while for all the DNS caches to expire.
7. While you are waiting those two days, test the setup by adding a line to your `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.txt` (Windows) or `/etc/hosts` (Mac, Linux) file.  It should have the IP address that GoDaddy is using (instead of `203.0.113.0`) as well as your domain name (instead of `mydomain.example`):

   ```
   203.0.113.0 mydomain.example www.mydomain.exmaple
   ```

   With that line in place, your site should start working immediatly (but just from your own computer.)  Remember to remove that line when you are done testing so that you know when DNS is done updating.
8. You can test that the DNS is set up correctly by using `dig` on the command line (or finding an online tester.) Verify that the IP address that GoDaddy is using is returned from the following commands.  These two could take a couple days to start working:

   ```
   dig mydomain.example
   dig www.mydomain.example
   ```

   These should start working immediately:

   ```
   dig @ns1.secureserver.net mydomain.example
   dig @ns1.secureserver.net www.mydomain.example
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your online.az for sure is not supported by Godaddy to be transferred. Maybe is a restricted domain.

ns1.secureserver.net and ns2.secureserver.net are the dns addresses that seem to be the natural option. By the way, they appear when you configure a new account under WHM.

But for some complicated Godaddy reason, they don't work.

Use ns45.domaincontrol.com  and ns46.domaincontrol.com instead.

Comment: Where are you getting the domaincontrol nameserver info?